Material change bleeds into other actions
I want to create two separate actions: one moves the object, and the other changes object color via a material.
For some reason color change appears during the move action.
In fact material changes play in every action, not only the first.
Is there any way to animate a material without affecting other actions?
Here is a sample code for reproducing my issue:
import bpy

if 'Cube' not in bpy.data.objects:
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
cube = bpy.data.objects['Cube']

# Create move action
move_action = bpy.data.actions.new(name='move')
cube.animation_data_create()
cube.animation_data.action = move_action
cube.keyframe_insert('location', index=0, frame=0)
cube.location[0] = 10
cube.keyframe_insert('location', index=0, frame=20)

# Create material
mat = cube.data.materials[0]
mat.use_nodes = True
links = mat.node_tree.links
node = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeMix')
node.data_type = 'RGBA'
node.inputs['A'].default_value = 1, 0, 0, 0
node.inputs['B'].default_value = 0, 0, 1, 0
links.new(node.outputs['Result'], mat.node_tree.nodes['Principled BSDF'].inputs['Base Color'])

# Create change color action
color_action = bpy.data.actions.new(name='color')
mat.node_tree.animation_data_create()
mat.node_tree.animation_data.action = color_action
node.inputs[0].default_value = 0
mat.node_tree.keyframe_insert('nodes[2].inputs[0].default_value', frame=0)
node.inputs[0].default_value = 1
mat.node_tree.keyframe_insert('nodes[2].inputs[0].default_value', frame=10)

It looks like Action Editor cannot see color action. But you can see material keyframes in the Dope Sheet.

